# How to add spaces between number and word in a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, compare, space

i have a lot of string which contains also number like : LOD140IXAL COMP 1X240GG

I would like to put whitespace between numbers and word if there isn't.
the number could be every where in the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is using regular expressions. Replacing the following monster with a single space should do the trick:

```
"(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])"
```

When applied to your example (`LOD140IXAL COMP 1X240GG`), it produces `LODIXAL COMP 1 X 240 MG`.

In a nutshell, the regex looks for a letter immediately followed by a digit, or a digit immediately followed by a letter, and inserts a space between them. To achieve this, it uses [zero-width assertions (lookahead and lookbehind)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like

```
myString.replaceAll( "(\\d)([A-Za-z])", "$1 $2" );
```