# How do I insert space when text changed from numeric input to alphabetic input and vice-versa?

Tags: android, textwatcher

Here is what I'm trying to do. I need to add a space between a numeric input and an alphabet input. I'm using the TextWatcher class but I could no get what exactly I want

if the input text is:

> APyt04XC2446

I need it as

> APyt 04 XC 2446

but i'm getting this:

> APyt 0 4 X C 2 4 4 6

This is my TextWatcher class:

```
public class FormattingTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
private static final String WHITE_SPACE = " ";
private String lastSource = EMPTY_STRING;

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String source = s.toString();

    if (!lastSource.equals(source)) {
        source = source.replace(WHITE_SPACE, EMPTY_STRING);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
            if ((s.charAt(i)>='a' && s.charAt(i)<='z') || (s.charAt(i)>='A' && s.charAt(i)<='Z')) {
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(WHITE_SPACE);
            }
            stringBuilder.append(source.charAt(i));
        }
        lastSource = stringBuilder.toString();
        s.replace(0, s.length(), lastSource);
    }
} }
```

kindly get me out of this... thanks

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833751/how-to-add-spaces-between-number-and-word-in-a-string-in-java) maybe help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add spaces between number and word in a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833751/how-to-add-spaces-between-number-and-word-in-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class FormattingTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
private static final String WHITE_SPACE = " ";
private String lastSource = EMPTY_STRING;

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String source = s.toString();

    int letterFlag = -1;

    if(Character.isLetter(character.charAt(0)){
       letterFlag = 0;
    }
    else{
       letterFlag = 1;
    }       

    for (int i = 1; i < source.length(); i++) {

          if(letterFlag == 1){
                if(Character.isLetter(character.charAt(i)){
                    stringBuilder.append(WHITE_SPACE);
                    letterFlag = 0;
                }
          }
          else{
               if(Character.isDigit(character.charAt(i)){
                    stringBuilder.append(WHITE_SPACE);
                    letterFlag = 1;
               }
          }

          stringBuilder.append(source.charAt(i));

   }


} }
```

Comment: what is character keyword initialization here

Comment: Just import it. It is class present in android studio, use alt+enter to import it.

Answer (score 0):

**For you**

```
public class FormattingTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
private static final String WHITE_SPACE = " ";
private String lastSource = EMPTY_STRING;

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String source = s.toString();

    if (!lastSource.equals(source)) {
        source = source.replace(WHITE_SPACE, EMPTY_STRING);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if ((str.charAt(0) >= 'a' && str.charAt(0) <= 'z') || (str.charAt(0) >= 'A' && str.charAt(0) <= 'Z'))
            flag = 1;
        else if ((str.charAt(0) >= '0' && str.charAt(0) <= '9'))
            flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (((str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z') || (str.charAt(i) >= 'A' && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z')) && flag == 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(WHITE_SPACE);
                stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
                flag = 1;
                continue;
            } else if ((str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') && flag == 1) {
                stringBuilder.append(WHITE_SPACE);
                stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
                flag = 0;
                continue;
            }
            stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
        lastSource = stringBuilder.toString();
        lastSource = lastSource.replaceAll("\\s+", " "); // it would remove the extra spaces between characters
        s.replace(0, s.length(), lastSource);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is adding space to the previous separation too..like this
APyt       04       XC 2442. the space between apty and 04 is continuously increasing

Comment: @Darshuu Fixed the issue you had. Answer **Updated**

Comment: fixed the spacing issue...but here comes another issue
when i press backspace in keypad it's add some garbage alphabets instead of deleting the last entered charater...this is only while removing alphabets but in case of letters it works fine

Comment: here is the thing happenning its showing as AP 31 gfffffgggfgfdfggs 5643...when i used back press for the 3 rd word